# SUM and multiple IIF Function condition in MDX

Tags: mdx, olap, iif-function

I have written MDX query below Here what i am doing try to getting result of tom based on the multiple condition applying in IIF function :

```
WITH 
  SET [kpi_study] AS 
    {[study].[study].[BHC June12]} 
  SET [geographic] AS 
    {[territory.market_hierarchy].[state].[MP]} 
  SET [brand] AS 
    {[brand.brand_hierarchy].[brand].[Gold Flake (Unspecified)]} 
  SET [edu12] AS 
    IIF
    (
      'All' = 'All'
     ,[education].[education].MEMBERS
     ,[education].[education].[All]
    ) 
     SET [town] as
    IIF(
        'All' = 'All'
        ,[territory.market_hierarchy].[town_class].MEMBERS
        ,[territory.market_hierarchy].[town_class].[All]
        )
    SET [occp] as
    IIF(
         'All' = 'All'
            ,[occupation].[occupation].MEMBERS
            ,[occupation].[occupation].[All]
       )
    MEMBER [Measures].[t] AS
    SUM(([edu12],[town],[occp]),[Measures].[tom])
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[t]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [funnel_analysis]
WHERE 
  {[kpi_study]*[geographic]*[brand]}
```

but getting some error.For single iif function its working fine ie: `**(SUM([edu12],[Measures].[tom]))**` unable to find out where i am doing wrong for multiple.

Comment: What is the error? Code looks good to me.

Comment: @SouravA: Error executing query. Please check the server logs or contact your administrator! unable to find out where i am doing wrong ..can u help me

Comment: @meff: Please suggest me any idea how we can solved that issue

Comment: Ok that error has nothing to do with MDX syntax. If I am not wrong the drive having your data file is running out of space.

Comment: This might help if you are on Saiku -  https://groups.google.com/a/saiku.meteorite.bi/forum/#!topic/user/9qGGCk4-tDk

Comment: @SouravA:Thanks a lot for your quick response.where i can find out the memory space.but as per my understanding the output is very fast and execution of rows is also very less. i don't know exactly whats wrong going on

Comment: Are you on Saiku? If yes, check out the above link.

Comment: @SouravA:Yes I am on Saiku

Comment: Check out the above URL. It has some info on the issue you're facing. Unfortunately, I haven't ever worked on Saiku, so can't help you any further.

Comment: @SouravA: Thanks for your quick response.I have gone through that link ...but that is not solution to move Mondrian 3 to 4 .but anyway thanks for your effort.I hope there is no error in syntax hopefully you have understood what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: @SouravA:can i get your contact details if you don't mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114621/discussion-between-sourava-and-sam140).

Comment: @SouravA: yes sure lets start ..thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do an explicit cross join.
Also please get rid of those single member custom sets that you're creating - this is not standard practice - just put them straight in your `WHERE` clause.

```
WITH 
  SET [edu12] AS 
    IIF(
     'All' = 'All'
     ,{[education].[education].MEMBERS}
     ,[education].[education].[All]
    ) 
  SET [town] as
    IIF(
      'All' = 'All'
      ,{[territory.market_hierarchy].[town_class].MEMBERS}
      ,[territory.market_hierarchy].[town_class].[All]
     )
  SET [occp] as
    IIF(
      'All' = 'All'
      ,{[occupation].[occupation].MEMBERS}
      ,[occupation].[occupation].[All]
     )
  MEMBER [Measures].[t] AS
    SUM(
       [edu12]
      *[town]
      *[occp]
      ,[Measures].[tom]
    )
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[t]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [funnel_analysis]
WHERE 
  (
   [study].[study].[BHC June12]
  ,[territory.market_hierarchy].[state].[MP]
  ,[brand.brand_hierarchy].[brand].[Gold Flake (Unspecified)]
  )
```

I'd prefer to try something like the following using `Aggregate`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [education].[education].[All].[edu12] AS 
    AGGREGATE(IIF(
     'All' = 'All'
     ,{[education].[education].MEMBERS}
     ,[education].[education].[All]
    )) 
  MEMBER [territory.market_hierarchy].[town_class].[All].[town] as
    AGGREGATE(IIF(
      'All' = 'All'
      ,{[territory.market_hierarchy].[town_class].MEMBERS}
      ,[territory.market_hierarchy].[town_class].[All]
     ))
  MEMBER [occupation].[occupation].[All].[occp] as
    AGGREGATE(IIF(
      'All' = 'All'
      ,{[occupation].[occupation].MEMBERS}
      ,[occupation].[occupation].[All]
     ))
  MEMBER [Measures].[t] AS
    (
       [education].[education].[All].[edu12]
      ,[territory.market_hierarchy].[town_class].[All].[town]
      ,[occupation].[occupation].[All].[occp]
      ,[Measures].[tom]
    )
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[t]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [funnel_analysis]
WHERE 
  (
   [study].[study].[BHC June12]
  ,[territory.market_hierarchy].[state].[MP]
  ,[brand.brand_hierarchy].[brand].[Gold Flake (Unspecified)]
  )
```

Exploratory script example - does this give you what you'd expect? If it is ok then move on to another bit of your more complex script:

```
WITH 
  SET [edu12] AS 
    IIF(
     'All' = 'All'
     ,{[education].[education].MEMBERS}
     ,[education].[education].[All]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [edu12] ON ROWS,
 {[Measures].[tom]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [funnel_analysis]
WHERE 
  (
   [study].[study].[BHC June12]
  ,[territory.market_hierarchy].[state].[MP]
  ,[brand.brand_hierarchy].[brand].[Gold Flake (Unspecified)]
  )
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick response .i have tried that as you have mentioned query but getting wrong result as expected .i don't know exactly why i am getting wrong result

Comment: Here instead of **All** if i am passing any other value then getting correct result.i don't know exactly where i am doing wrong.can you please help me

Comment: @sam140 so if you leave as `'All' = 'All'` you get an error, but is you do `'All' = 'blahblah'` then it is ok ?

Comment: yes if i am using 'All'='blahblah' then getting correct result.but if i am using 'All' ='All' then getting wrong result. i don't know exactly where i am doing wrong so plz guide me where i am doing wrong

Comment: @sam140 a little bit more difficult for me to help - you need to break the script down into little bits - run each bit and see where it is not what you expect - I will add an example of one exploratory script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114659/discussion-between-sam140-and-whytheq).

Comment: this giving perfect result:WITH 
  SET [edu12] AS 
    IIF(
     'All' = 'All'
     ,{[education].[education].MEMBERS}
     ,[education].[education].[All]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [edu12] ON ROWS,
 {[Measures].[tom]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [funnel_analysis]
WHERE 
  (
   [study].[study].[BHC June12]
  ,[territory.market_hierarchy].[state].[MP]
  ,[brand.brand_hierarchy].[brand].[Gold Flake (Unspecified)]
  ) need your help to add more IIF function plz guide me

Comment: Exploratory script is working fine .can you plz help me to add one more iif function getting as expecting result

Comment: can we have some personal chat i will explain exactly my problem if possible.